# call executables in c++ and run in parallel

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, fork, openmp

In C++, I'm calling an executable file using system("./filename blahblah"); Now since there are many iterations I want to put them in parallel

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for( int i = 0; i < 999; ++i )
system("./filename blahblah");
```

But I'm quite sure the above won't work, since #pragma omp is an extension of C++ compiler and can only work to modify the compilation of C++ lines. system() calls the terminal shell to process a command, and #pragma omp is not going to affect the execution of that command.

Is there a way to work around with this? I do think there is an approach with fork() & exec() in GNU but I don't know exactly how. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: Is there any dependency between the loop iterations? Can several "./filename blahblah" run concurrently? If the former is negative and the later is positive, then the solution you proposed might just work... Just add a `-fopenmp` or whatever compiler option you need to activate the support of OpenMP and that might be it.

Comment: The [`system`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) function actually calls the shell, which means you can use all the features of the shell, like putting processes in the background with the trailing `&`.

Comment: It is operating system specific. I guess you are on Linux

Comment: I guessing that we can specify which core to use in shell command? Like in c++ I can put something like system("./executable blahblah -using core 2")

Comment: @yuquan: no you generally cannot. But google for "CPU affinity".

Comment: @Gilles, you mean that when the executable is called four times, the system will allocate each of the four jobs into one of my four cores?

Comment: Yes, provided you set properly the [OMP_NUM_THREADS](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/OMP_005fNUM_005fTHREADS.html#OMP_005fNUM_005fTHREADS) environment variable to tell how many cores to use and the [OMP_PLACES](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/OMP_005fPLACES.html#OMP_005fPLACES) one to give the affinity (if you want to). Moreover, your can also use `num_threads()` and `proc_bind()` directly at the `omp parallel for` level to avoid using environment variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to use [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html), [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) and some other [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) (e.g. [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) is useful for an [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop), and you might need one) etc...

I won't explain how, read the [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) book (available online) which has several chapters devoted to the subject (and most of them are relevant for other POSIX systems such as MaCOSX).

You might be interested in [MPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface).

BTW, having one thousand *running* processes is unreasonable on most computers. You'll better limit yourself to a dozen running processes at most (e.g. have some [pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pool_%28computer_science%29) of processes).
You typically want no much more than one running process or thread (i.e. task) per [core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-core_processor) (and slightly more if you have an [hyper-threaded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading) Intel processor). If you have too many running processes, your system would be unresponsive and the overall performance would suffer (the [scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_%28computing%29) would have too many active tasks to manage).

You might be interested in [batch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_processing) systems (e.g. you could [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) a [`batch`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_%28Unix%29) command; on MacOSX see also [launchd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd)).

Comment: Typically? Why would you ever want more threads/processes than cores?

Comment: @jco: When you know or have the intuition that some processes would sleep (or wait for IO) most of the time

Comment: Ah, thanks, makes sense. But if they were all computing something, then it wouldn't make sense, right?

Comment: @jco: if you have too much running processes, the scheduler would do its best, but the overall system performance is likely to fall.